# pdf notes with mathematical equations

Tags: osx, note-taking, math

I'm looking for a program where I'm able to annotate PDF files with notes, including correct mathematical equations (on mac).
So far the only way I found was writing the equations with LaTeX in a different program and inserting those via screenshots.
Looking forwards to your suggestions.